# Как можно поделить таблицу с симметричными данными пополам?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Допустим, есть таблица:

```
ID1 ID2    
1   2    
1   3    
1   4    
2   1    
3   1    
4   1
```

Как я могу получить какой-нибудь конкретный кусок?

Например:

```
ID1 ID2    
1 2    
1 3    
1 4
```

Что-то экспериментировал с JOIN'ми, но к результату не пришел...

Comment: Сходу пришла такая идея
`select id1, id2 from table t1
where t1.id1<t1.id2 and exists
        (select id1, id2 from table t2 where t1.id1 = t2.id2 and t1.id2=t2.id1)`
Проверить данный запрос пока возможности нет

Comment: @АмирЗакиров вроде, похоже на правду, но это условие t1.id1<t1.id2 не нравится. Мне кажется, что в каких-то отдельных случаях не отработает.

Comment: exists, вроде, излишний и без него половина возвращается.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id1 < id2`

Comment: *условие t1.id1<t1.id2 не нравится. Мне кажется, что* Продумайте и измените формулировки. Сейчас, уж извините, описание задачи совершенно невменяемое. И напрашивающееся на ответ *"получить какой-нибудь конкретный кусок" можно как-нибудь*.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Exists отбросит значения. у которых нет симметричной пары. Если вы уверены, что все данные в таблице у вас симметричные, то можете его не использовать.

Comment: SELECT id1,id2 FROM table WHERE t1 BEATWEEN 1 AND 2;

Comment: @Akina, `<` не прокатит, если могут быть одинаковые значения, должно быть `<=`. А вообще, чего ж не в ответы-то? А то я сначала ответ пишу, а потом комменты читаю)))

Comment: Всё, накидал версий, если что не работает, говори, постараюсь поправить.

Comment: @АмирЗакиров, кажется, тебе в ответы. Впрочем, мне кажется, inner join был бы поэффективнее exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Идеальный вариант, если зеркальные записи гарантированно присутствуют:

```
select id1, id2 from tbl where id1 <= id2
```

Comment: Вроде, работает. Но есть доп вопрос: сейчас у меня гуляет выборка. Т.е родительская запись к которой крепятся N других ID находится,то справа, то слева. А можно как-то сделать так, что бы строго с одной стороны у меня были родительские записи, а справа дочернии?

Comment: Т.е хочу, что бы было не так  {1,2},{1,3},{4,6},{7,6}, а так {1,2},{1,3},{6,4},{6,7}

Comment: Не было в вопросе таких условий...

Comment: Да. Поэтому я и написал, что доп. пожелание, если такое можно провернуть.

Comment: @iluxa1810, там думать надо...

Comment: Ну ок. Попробую через группировками доп фильтр по кол-ву к вашему запросу добавить.

Comment: Это скорее к соседнему ответу.

Answer (score 0):

Что имеется ввиду конкретнее под куском?

Если просто часть таблицы:

Сверху:

```sql
select top N {percent} {columns}
from TABLE
order by TABLE.COLUMN
```

Снизу (посложнее):

```sql
select {columns} from 
(select top N {percent} {columns} from TABLE order by TABLE.COLUMN desc)
order by TABLE.COLUMN asc
```

Чтобы выбрать из середины нужно исхитриться сложнее. Первое, что приходит в голову - использовать курсор и завести переменную индекса курсора и выводить строки с какой-то по какую-то.

---

Если Вы уверены, что данные симметричны, и нужно вывести только строго половину:

```sql
select top 50 percent {columns} from TABLE
```

Comment: Я привел пример. Кусок- это конкретная симметричная часть.

Comment: На самом деле, из примера мало что понятно без должного описания. По крайней мере мне.

Comment: Не сработает если могут быть записи с равными значениями.

Comment: Кстати, а с каких пор адекватно использовать top без order by? Вроде как он может что угодно выдать.

Answer (score 0):

Если нет уверенности, что таблица содержит все зеркальные записи, а надо выбрать все уникальные пары, то можно выбрать минимальное и максимальное значения, но стоит заметить, что выбранная строка тогда может отсутствовать в таблице.

```
select distinct
  (case when id1 < id2 then id1 else id2 end) as id1,
  (case when id1 < id2 then id2 else id1 end) as id2
from
  tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нет уверенности, что все симметричные записи добавлены и нужны именно строки из таблицы:

```
select
  COALESCE(t1.id1, t2.id1) as id1,
  COALESCE(t1.id2, t2.id2) as id2
from
  tbl t1 outer join tbl t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id2 and t1.id2 = t2.id1
```

Если записи, для которых отсутствуют соответствующие симметричные, надо выкидывать, то ещё проще:

```
select
  t1.id1,
  t1.id2
from
  tbl t1 inner join tbl t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id2 and t1.id2 = t2.id1
```