# Как можно вычленить 1 группу данных из похожих групп?

Tags: sql-server

Это, можно сказать, продолжение [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/974276/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC) вопроса, но я изучил подробнее входные данные и все оказалось иначе, что вышло бы за рамки того вопроса.

Допустим, есть таблица:

```
ID1 ID2

1   2

1   3

1   4

2   1

2   3

2   4

3   1

3   2

3   4

4   1

4   2

4   3
```

Как вы видите, если на запись А есть N ID2, то есть такая запись Б из множества

ID2, которая включает в себя все записи из А включая саму А исключая Б.

Я хочу получить конкретно какую-нибудь 1 группу, например:

```
ID1 ID2

1   2

1   3

1   4
```

В принципе, я прошелся по этой таблице курсором:

```
Declare @ID1 INT
Declare @ID2 INT
Declare cur Cursor FOR
select * from tbl
ORDER BY 1

Open Cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur into @ID1,@ID2


    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM NewTable WHERE [ID2]=@ID1)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO NewTable (ID1, ID2) VALUES (@ID1,@ID2)
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur into @ID1,@ID2
    END
    Close Cur
    Deallocate cur
```

, но это было крайне долго...

Можно ли как-нибудь элегантно это сделать запросом?

Comment: То ли я чего-то недопонял, то ли Вы чего-то недоговариваете, но как насчёт `SELECT id1, id2 FROM tbl WHERE id1 = 1 AND id2 != 1`?

Comment: @SergeyNudnov ну так это пример только. Представьте реальную такую таблицу на пару миллионов записей такого типа.

Comment: Не могу. Ваш пример полностью укладывается в этот запрос. И, кстати, Ваш код - тоже. Вот эти вещи насчёт множеств в вопросе - попробуйте переформулировать. Непонятно...

Comment: Ну где-то дальше могут быть записи, например {10,11} и {11,10}, дальше {100,101},{100,102},{100,103},{101,100},{101,102},{101,103},{102,100},{102,101},{102,103},{103,100},{103,101},{103,102} . По идее, логика должна быть видна